# Generate unique ascending numerical id in django model field

Tags: django, django-models

```
Class Car(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField('Type', max_length=100)
     code = models.CharField('Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Considering I want to make a list of cars depending on their types. I have a model and fields like the above code, 
I want to make the code uniquely increment based on the type of the car. For instance, if an instance of a car was created with type field as 'HD', then the code would be 'HD-0000001'. The next model created with the type HD as well would be HD-0000002, so on, so forth. If another type is given, it will save as 'type' + 'the last saved number + 1'.

I know I have to do something in the save() function, but I can't figure out how to make it unique based on different types.

Any suggestions will be truly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could write your class as follows:

```
Class Car(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField('Type', max_length=100)
    code = models.IntegerField('Code', default=-1)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.code == -1:
            max_code=Car.objects.filter(type=self.type).aggregate(max_code=Max('code'))
            self.code = max_code.get('max_code',0)+1 if max_code else 1
        return super(Car, self).save(*args, **kw)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('type', 'code')
```

So, you should never save the attribute code, because before first save the object get the last code number for it's type and set self 'code' with de next value.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.